# How To Make A Two-Channel Audio Mixer?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, mixer, preamp

I'd like to make a 2-channel audio mixer. I'll connect one of the entrances to my phone with an aux cord. I'm going to put my headphone mic on the other one. I'll also connect a potentiometer to both channels separately and adjust the volume. I'm going to combine these two channels into one channel and connect the output output to my computer. My goal is to record audio on a computer. Is there a circuit diagram that has the properties I want? I would be glad if you send. Thanks.

EDIT: For example, this scheme seems to have exactly what I want. But if it works I'm not sure. Do you think I should try this?[image]

Comment: Isn't your phone a stereo output? Did you think it was mono? Maybe it is? If stereo then is the output meant to be stereo too? If yes, then which way do you pan the microphone or do you mix it to both channels. If yes and yes then your diagram needs modifying and don't bother using the LM3900, a fairly normal op-amp will do. You haven't mentioned your power source.

Comment: "*I'll connect one of the entrances [inputs?] to my phone with an aux cord.*" You seem to be trying to mix your microphone with another signal source. Is this correct? The mic input will be very sensitive. Are you aware that the mic input is mono so you can't record stereo.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, my phone is stereo. I don't just want to connect my phone, I want to connect other devices. For example, mp3 player, laptop, etc. I plan to use 9v as a power source, but I can comply with the circuit diagram that you recommend, no problem. Actually, what I'm trying to do is, [link](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media.evaly.com.bd/watermarked/2019-07-14_075354.753752Silver_Color_Women_Finger_Ring__57.jpg)

Comment: @Transistor I understand, thank you. Then I'll have to find another circuit. This is the device I'm trying to make. [link](file:///C:/Users/oly_k/Desktop/2019-07-14_075354.753752Silver_Color_Women_Finger_Ring__57.jpg) But sound effects etc. I don't want. I just want a microphone and line input and I want to check the volume of these two channels.

Comment: You want auto-tune, pitch-bend and reverb too? If so it sounds like you might be out of your depth.

Comment: Oh you don't want those effect? I feel like I'm wasting my time because it's not clear what you do want.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm sorry I made you feel that way. I know what I really want, but I have a hard time expressing myself because my English is not strong. No, I don't want sound effects or anything like that. I just want to connect my microphone and external audio source, Do volume control separately, and merge

Comment: You've posted a link to a file on your hard drive but it's OK - I wouldn't follow a link to "Silver_Color_Women_Finger_Ring" anyway.